# Tautology: extensive periods of time

Tags: grammaticality

I noticed that the phrase:

"extensive periods of time" contained the tautology "periods of time".

Does the sentence "extensive amounts of time" also contain this tautology? Or is there a word that is able to represent the same meaning?

Comment: What exactly do you think is tautological?

Comment: What's the rest of the sentence? Might be clear with just "extensive periods".

Comment: It isn't a tautology; *periods of time* distinguishes meaning against *extensive periods of flooding* and *extensive wastes of time*.

Comment: I'd agree that there's a degree of tautology here. But idiomaticity trumps over-zealous 'rule'-keeping every time.

Comment: I agree that "period of time" is redundant: "period" here means a stretch of time. "Periods of flooding" means "stretches of time in which flooding occurred"; "flooding" isn't replacing "time" in that example, because time is still implied in "periods."

Comment: You can have very short periods of time.

Comment: @marcellothearcane It’s not _extensive_ that’s the tautology but _period of time_ – all periods are time by definition (except perhaps menstrual ones, which has its origins in the same meaning, but is rather far from it now).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we cannot tell whether you are asking whether something is actually ungrammatical by the laws of English syntax and morphology, or whether it is merely redundant, repetitive, and tautological with no relation to grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Tautology is:

> the saying of the same thing twice over in different words, generally considered to be a fault of style (*e.g. they arrived one after the other in succession*).
>   <sub>ODO, via Google</sub>

It is important to understand that a *period of time* can be **any length**, and your premise that 'a period of time' repeats the meaning of extensive is incorrect.

This also holds for '*extensive amounts of time*', since *amounts of time* holds no indication as to the duration.

Comment: Maybe I formulated the question incorrect... My premise was actually not the repetition of  'extensive', but the fact that 'a period' is always 'of time'